# Is it possible to send a zip code to maps V3 API to return a map centered on that zip code?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, zipcode

I need to display a map on a web page - I have the user's address info, but for security purposes I need the map to be centered on the centroid point of their zip code or city, not their specific address.

**Is it possible to submit only a zip code to the Google maps V3 API and have it return a map of a postal code / zip-code?**

Or do I have to first geocode the zip code and submit the lat/long?

This is how I was doing it using Yahoo...

```
//assign the zipcode from the database to the zipcode variable
zipCode = oUser("zipCode")

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.8&appid=x">
</script>

// create the container 
<div id="map" class="map">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Create a map object 
var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map')); 
// Display the map centered on the zipcode 
map.drawZoomAndCenter("<%=zipCode%>", 5); 
</script>
```

If you go to google.com/maps and enter a 5 digit US zip code, the website will return a map that is centered on the central point of that zip code.  The script above did the same thing on my website  (until Yahoo discontinued its map service).

I’d like to do the same thing using the Google API – but everything I’ve seen so far indicates that I have to send the long/lat string of the zip-code centroid point to the API - which is fine (we have a zip-code/long/lat table in the database) – it just requires more server work on our end – or on Google’s if I geocode a zipcode on the fly). I’d like to keep this as efficient as possible and send only the postal_code if possible.

Can that be done?

Thanks,

- Michael

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code in your comment and possible rephrase your title.Also mention you have a database of zipcode coordinates. I am deleting my answer as it does not meet the new criteria

Comment: You need to geocode the zip code/city before center the map

Comment: Isn't it a bit surprising that Google provides for a web visitor to google.com/maps/ to enter just a zip code - but does not provide a built-in function or routine for allowing the same thing through their API?

Comment: settled for writing a function to first retrieve the zipcode of the user from our database, then query our zipcodes table for the long/lat of the zipcode (centroid) - and submit that through API as normal. Works great - was just hoping to save a little server-side overhead.